# Error while installing firebase @angular/fire

Tags: angular, npm, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angularfire

I am working on an angular chat application. When I tried to install firebase through "npm install --save firebase @angular/fire". It gave me a list of errors. As far as I understood, there was a problem in the version of npm-pre-grp and npm-grp. I even installed the @latest of both but still, the problem persists.

```
C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat>npm install angularfire2 firebase
--save npm WARN deprecated angularfire2@5.0.2: AngularFire has moved, we're now @angular/fire

grpc@1.13.1 install C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

 - node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.13.1
   and node@8.12.0 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source
   compile with node-gyp) node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error ENOENT: no such
   file or directory, open 'C:\path\to\cert_authority_file_base64.cer'
   gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:
   C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE
   -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]; gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1 gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print
   "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]; gyp ERR! stack                    
   ^ gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax gyp ERR! stack gyp ERR!
   stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12) gyp
   ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
   (internal/child_process.js:915:16) gyp ERR! stack     at
   Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:336:11) gyp ERR!
   stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
   Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
   Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12) gyp ERR! System
   Windows_NT 10.0.17134 gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program
   Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
   Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
   "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
   "--module=C:\\Coding_data\\Angular\\base-chat\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node"
   "--module_name=grpc_node"
   "--module_path=C:\\Coding_data\\Angular\\base-chat\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown"
   "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc gyp ERR! node -v
   v8.12.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR!
   build error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
   configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
   --module=C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown
   --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
   (C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
   (internal/child_process.js:915:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134 node-pre-gyp ERR!
   command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Coding_data\\Angular\\base-chat\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp"
   "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc node-pre-gyp ERR!
   node -v v8.12.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute 'C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
   configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
   --module=C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Coding_data\Angular\base-chat\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown
   --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
   notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! grpc@1.13.1
   install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
   --library=static_library` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.13.1 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
   above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
   C:\Users\Mayank\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-02T05_01_54_885Z-debug.log
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and I had to install node LTS (8.12.0) version instead of the current (11.0.0) version and that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This worked when nothing on the node-gyp website did, thank you. I was using 10.13.0 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps others, as recommended [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15507), running the following worked for me:

```
npm install firebase --force
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version of  the node , downgrade your node version and try again it will work .

Answer (score 0):

try ng add @angular/fire, it will install both firebase and related dependencies

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31363281)

Comment: well it worked for me and may be the above answers works but that doesn't mean there is an easy way to do that using ng add method and please don't judge people by reputation !!!